# Issuu, how to write issuu.documents.list request correctly?

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest

I want to use issuu.documents.list to list my document from issuu, It work fine. But when I add two more parameters startIndex and pageSize, it doesn't work.
Here is my signing request:

> [apiSecret]accessprivateactionissuu.documents.listapiKey[apiKey]startIndex0pageSize20formatxmlresponseParamstitle,documentId

and My request url:

> http://api.issuu.com/1_0?action=issuu.documents.list&apiKey=[apiKey]&access=private&startIndex=0&pageSize=20&format=xml&responseParams=title%2CdocumentId&signature=[signature]

So, may you show me what's wrong in my syntax with startIndex and pageSize parameters?
Many thanks,

Comment: Can you provide the error message, if any, that you are receiving.  "Doesn't work" can mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 1):

All requests to the issuu api have to be signed (as you know). Before creating an md5 hash of your signature, you must first order all the keys alphabetically.

**WRONG**

`[apiSecret]accessprivateactionissuu.documents.listapiKey[apiKey]startIndex0pageSize20formatxmlresponseParamstitle,documentId`

**CORRECT**

`[apiSecret]accessprivateactionissuu.documents.listapiKey[apiKey]pageSize20formatxmlresponseParamstitle,documentIdstartIndex0`

So in your example, you have startIndex positioned before responseParams when it really should go after it.

Alphabetically ordering the keys in your signature is a requirement of Issuu's API as documented here. http://issuu.com/services/api/signingrequests.html